# Change path for default file:///android_asset on Cordova project

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

I am currently working on a mobile application developed thanks to Cordova framework.

I have no issues when I am testing my application with Ripple and Google Chrome, it is working fine. But, when I am testing on my own smartphone, my application is not able to load my HTML templates.

Visual Studio console displays :

```
E/AndroidProtocolHandler( 2758): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/templates/login.html
```

It means that my application don't find login.html file, but it's because the real path is : `file:///android_asset/www/templates/login.html`

So, where can I change this global path and add `www` folder ? Any idea ?

Thanks you very much for you help ! :)

**Note :**
If I change the route path in my angular router to `urlTemplate: ../www/templates/login.html` instead of `urlTemplate: ../templates/login.html`, it works fine on my smartphone, but not on Ripple ...

Comment: Did you install drivers for your phone also a previous version of node may be required. Took me a whole day to set it up the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `base` tag, which can be use to set default base to relative paths.

Prototype:

```
<base href="file:///android_asset/www/" target="_blank">
```

usage:

```
<img src="templates/login.html">
```